# Trouble connecting UR5 robot with moveit! and Rviz

Tags: rviz, moveit, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After following the Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot tutorial the launch demo will not work, it reports:

ResourceNotFound: ur5_moveit_config
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/groovy/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks

When I run:
roslaunch ur5_moveit_config/launch/demo.launch

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174597/trouble-connecting-ur5-robot-with-moveit!-and-rviz/) by [PartyMaine](https://answers.ros.org/users/18956/partymaine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS Indigo, so I'm not sure if my answer makes sense foor Groovy, but I think it applies for both versions (and otherwise it may lead you in the right direction).

It seems if the ur5_moveit_config package cannot be found by the roslaunch application. So did you perform the following steps:

1. Download and install the universal_robot module, or create the ur5_moveit_config yourself using the tutorial?
2. Then build everything, using 'catkin_make'?
3. Setup the environment for your workspace (i.e. to set the right paths), using 'source devel/setup.bash'?

---

Originally posted by [wouter_tnl](https://answers.ros.org/users/20414/wouter_tnl/) with karma: 110 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0